# What does copy/paste actually do? Where is the copied information stored? - VBA

Tags: windows, excel, vba

I'm just wondering exactly what is happening when you do something like

```
Range("test").Copy
```

Is there some sort of Windows "Global" copy/paste space that stores this information? How can you access this?

Comment: Ever heard of the `Clipboard`?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648709(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[The `Copy` method:](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff837718.aspx)

> Copies the specified range to the Clipboard.

You can easily verify this by copying a range of text (from an email, web browser, Excel spreadsheet, etc.) and then go in to your other document and paste it.

You can *access* the clipboard from the MSForms.DataObject class:

http://www.cpearson.com/excel/Clipboard.aspx

```
Dim DataObj As Object ' MSForms.DataObject
Dim S As String

Set DataObj = CreateObject("MSForms.DataObject")
DataObj.GetFromClipboard
S = DataObj.GetText
Debug.Print S
```

Chip Pearson's site has some other examples for working with, manipulating, putting items in, etc., with the Clipboard.